# Flutter Contacts and calling

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a function that takes in a query which is the contact name. I am fetching all contacts in flutter, converting it from iterable contacts to list contacts. And then fetching it's callable phone number, and automatically calling it. It's not working. I am calling this function (autocall) from main.dart. Pls Help.
here is the code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
import 'package:fast_contacts/fast_contacts.dart';
import 'main.dart';
var i=0;
final List<Contact> _contacts=[];
Future<void> getContacts() async {
  List <Contact> _contacts = (await FastContacts.allContacts).toList();
}
void autocall(String to_be_called){
  getContacts();
  while(i<_contacts.length)
  {
    if(to_be_called.toLowerCase()==_contacts[i].structuredName.toString().toLowerCase())
    {
      FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(_contacts[i].phones[0].toString());
      i=0;
      break;
    }
    else
      {
        i++;
      }
  }
}**
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @CodeMaster no error messages, just it's not placing the call. It's a part of my alan ai, voice automation project

Comment: I don't see how the `final List<Contact> _contacts=[];` variable will be filled since it is declared outside the `getContacts()` method and then declares within the method itself and second that the `getContacts()` method is async and would need await in `autocall`;

Answer (score 0):

See if this fixes it.

```
var i=0;
Future<List<Contact>> getContacts() async {
  var _contacts = (await FastContacts.allContacts).toList();
  return _contacts;
}
void autocall(String to_be_called) async {
  var _contacts = await getContacts();
  while(i<_contacts.length)
  {
    if(to_be_called.toLowerCase()==_contacts[i].structuredName.toString().toLowerCase())
    {
      FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(_contacts[i].phones[0].toString());
      i=0;
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: really aprreciate u helping me out, but no it didnt work sorry :(

Comment: I just changed how the list is loaded, the rest I don't know what you're holding.